# Properties of functions of normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$As an extension of this question ([covariance of normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74997/covariance-of-normal-distribution)), I'd like to give a specific example, and ask what we can deduce about this by imposing assumptions.

Suppose $X\sim N(0,4)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1),$ and let the function $Z=2+3X+Y$.

We can deduce the mean of $Z$ quite easily, and we can find an expression for the variance (in terms of $\Cov(X,Y)$). Is there anything we could say beyond this? I do not think we can make any statements about $\Cov(X,Z)$ or $\Cov(Y,Z)$, without knowing $\Cov(X,Y)$, which we cannot calculate.

Suppose we impose that the vector $(X,Y,Z)$ is multivariate normal. Could we say anything then?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the definitions. Put $Z=2+3X+Y.$ Then $Cov(X,Z)=Cov(X,2+3X+Y)=Cov(X,2)+3Cov(X,X)+Cov(X,Y)=0+3Var(X)+Cov(X,Y).$

In general, just use the linear properties of covariance.

Answer (score 0):

$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Z) = \operatorname{cov}(X,2+3X +Y) = 3\cdot 3 + \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) $$

> Suppose we impose that the vector $(X,Y,Z)$ is multivariate normal. Could we say anything then?

If you mean could we say more about variances and covariances of linear functions of $X$ and $Y,$ we cannot, **because those are completely determined by the variances and the covariance of $X$ and $Y.$** However, if any nonlinear functions were involved, then we would probably be at a loss without knowing more about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ than their covariance, but if we assumed joint normality, then then more could be said. For example, we would know the distribution of $X^4$ in that case.